# groovy "matches" regex

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

we have different versions like this

```
20.0.19.198
18.7b.0.2
19.1.1b.1
20.acme.0.234
20.xyzname.0.123
20.helloworld.0.345
```

We tried using this below regex, it is returning "true" for all above versions, please help to correct  the regex where above 1st-3rd versions are true "release" versions". For 4th, 5th and 6th lines, we want to make  "false" for release versions (theres many varieties where , for 4th, 5th, 6th line, the string after 1st dot is not like how 1st,2nd,3rd looks.

```
def isReleaseVerson(String version){
    return version.matches("(\\d+)\\.(.*)\\.(\\d+)")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put the code like so:

```
boolean isReleaseVersion( String s ) {
  s ==~ /^\d+\.\d+\w*\.\w+\.\d+$/
}

def list = '''\
  20.0.19.198
  18.7b.0.2
  19.1.1b.1
  20.acme.0.234
  20.xyzname.0.123
  20.helloworld.0.345'''.stripIndent().readLines().each{
  println "$it -> ${isReleaseVersion( it )}"
}
```

prints

```
20.0.19.198 -> true
18.7b.0.2 -> true
19.1.1b.1 -> true
20.acme.0.234 -> false
20.xyzname.0.123 -> false
20.helloworld.0.345 -> false
```